# To find determinant of a 3*3 matrix in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

hi guys I wanted to find determinant of a 3X3 matrix using c++ I wrote the following code but its not working. Can someone please point out the bug?
Thanks in advance

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
#define R 3

int main(){
    fstream f;
    int x=1;
    f.open("values");//open the file that contains the matrix
    int** A;
    A=new int*[R];
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        A[i]=new int[R];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<R;j++){
            f>>A[i][j];//input values
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        x=x*A[i][i];
        for(int j=0;j<R;j++){   
            if(A[i][i]!=0){A[i][j]=A[i][j]/A[i][i];}//using Gauss Jordan Elimination method
        }
        for(int k=i+1;k<R;k++){//going at the next row...basically sweeping a column
            for(int y=i;y<R;y++){
                A[k][y]=A[k][y]-(A[k][i]*A[i][y]);//sweeping
            }           
        }
    }
    f.close();
    int z=1;
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        z=z*A[i][i];//in case all a[i][i] are zero z will be zero and hence the answer
    }
    cout<<"The det  is"<<endl<<x*z<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Frustrated Coder, please remember to format your code :) Can you please provide more details, how does the code not work? What errors does it produce?

Comment: Is this homework ? If not, what do you want to do ? Compute 3x3 determinants or nxn determinants ? In the former case, use the explicit formula. In the latter, use LU decomposition and LAPACK.

Comment: @ALL: This is what I am doing after being taught Linear Algebra. Yes I can do that for n*n matrix by just inputting R from the user.
The error: it always gives answer as 2 even for a matrix with all entries 0!!!!
I feel GEM is more relevant here.
I have developed this code so that I can cross check my answers when solving problems.

Comment: And if we give you answers are you likely to accept one of them?

Comment: @Frustrated Coder why not just use a unit test?

Comment: @Frustrated Coder: Do you know what a debugger is? If yes, do use it and you will find your error. If not, do google it

Comment: @Frustrated Coder: Can you explain me what you want to do writing for(int k=i+1;k<R;k++) in this place i even not defined (but VS6.0 can compile it)?

Comment: @Mihran I want to increment the rows! I has already been set to 1 in the parent loop buddy!

Comment: Its giving floating point exception now. What could be the reason?

Comment: @Frustrated Coder:  If you made a change and it throws a floating-point exception, we're not going to figure it out unless you show us the new code.  Please show us the code, and tell us exactly what's happening (including showing us what line things happen on).  One thing you could do is print out the matrix so you can verify it contains what you think it does.

Comment: Single-character variable names for everything? I cannot recall the last time I saw such obfuscated code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting some debug in there to try and work out where your '2' is coming from. For example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

#define R (3)

int main(){
    fstream f;
    int x=1;
    f.open("values");//open the file that contains the matrix

    // Assign and populate A
    int** A = new int*[R];
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        A[i]=new int[R];
    }
    f.close();

    // Show what we started with
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<R;j++){
            f>>A[i][j];//input values
            printf("[%04d] ",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Find the determinant
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        x=x*A[i][i];
        for(int j=0;j<R;j++){
            if(A[i][i]!=0){
                A[i][j]=A[i][j]/A[i][i];
            }//using Gauss Jordan Elimination method
        }
        for(int k=i+1;k<R;k++){
            for(int y=i;y<R;y++){
                A[k][y]=A[k][y]-(A[k][i]*A[i][y]);
            }           
        }
    }

    // Show the resulting matrix
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<R;j++){
            f>>A[i][j];//input values
            printf("[%04d] ",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }       

    int z=1;
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        z=z*A[i][i];
    }
    cout<<"x is"<<endl<<x;<<endl<<"z is"<<endl<<z;<<endl;
    cout<<"The det  is"<<endl<<x*z;<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

...is more clearly formatted and should help identify where the problem is coming from.

Comment: oops.. just spotted an error in my printf's - change a[i][j] to A[i][j]

Comment: from which line? ..and what does your input file look like?